# ASP.Net VNext after dnu publish not working on linux machines

Tags: docker, dnx, .net-core

I am running the vanilla ASP.Net VNext hello world application with dnx. When i perform "dnx . run", it runs just fine. But when i am using "dnu publish" to create the self contained package (as a result of which it creates web.cmd), it fails to run on linux with the errors

```
root@Xavier:~/Net/HelloWorldCore/bin/output# web.cmd
web.cmd: command not found
```

i tired doing "chmod 777 web.cmd", it then fails to recognize dnx

```
root@Xavier:~/Net/HelloWorldCore/bin/output# chmod 777 web.cmd 
root@Xavier:~/Net/HelloWorldCore/bin/output# ./web.cmd
./web.cmd: line 1: $'\r': command not found
./web.cmd: line 2: @dnx.exe: command not found
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

```
root@Xavier:~/dnvm list

Active Version              Runtime Arch Location             Alias
------ -------              ------- ---- --------             -----
       1.0.0-beta4          coreclr x64  ~/.dnx/runtimes      
       1.0.0-beta5          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      default
       1.0.0-beta6-12207    coreclr x64  ~/.dnx/runtimes      
       1.0.0-beta6-12207    mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      
  *    1.0.0-beta4          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes
```

Comment: $bash web
seems to do the trick but i now get different error

System.DllNotFoundException: httpapi.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UnsafeNclNativeMethods/HttpApi:HttpInitialize (Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UnsafeNclNativeMethods/HttpApi/HTTPAPI_VERSION,uint,void*)

Comment: Please discard. 
running bash kestrel does the charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you don't run the .cmd files. Cmd is just for Windows. Just run the command name, without any extension: `./web`.

Comment: thanks! 
yeh figured it out. Looks like web is also not supported on linux. I have to use kestrel.